# Ionic 3 / auth0 error when running in browser

Tags: auth0, ionic3

I'm trying to follow the Ionic quickstart for here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic2

When I do this ( or run the sample ) and run "ionic serve" I get the following error when the login button is clicked

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined
    at Function.Browser.isAvailable (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115566:30)
    at getAgent (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115598:23)
    at CordovaAuth.authorize (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:64570:3)
    at AuthService.login (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:64460:16)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/HomePage.ngfactory.js:39:29)
    at handleEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12083:138)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13291:42)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12879:12)
    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:9058:21)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:9648:38
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:39395:53)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12256)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4394:37)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12177)
    at n.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7153)
```

Seems to work OK in ios but not browser. Why is this? Is it because auth0 sdk now uses the safariviewcontroller instead of InAppBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the page why:

> Please note that PKCE authentication requires testing on either an emulated or real device. Attempting authentication when testing in the browser will fail because PKCE requires a device browser.

Comment: Why have auth0 changed their SDK to work this way? Makes testing ionic apps very hard

Comment: @C.Woza I believe to make things easier and more secure, you can look at the Cordova plugin docs for more info:
https://auth0.github.io/auth0-cordova/